# C# Rectangle point registry

Tags: c#

I have some code here that is not registering to ever be true and I have been lost for a few hours. I apologize if its just a stupid mistake.

```
bool Bdrag;
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point Floater = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(200, 200 ,40 , 40);
    Rectangle Rect2 = new Rectangle(250, 250, 40, 40);
    if(Rect.Contains(Floater))
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Bdrag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Bdrag = false;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("success 1");
        if(Rect2.Contains(Floater) && Bdrag == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("success 2!!")
            }
     }
}
```

I am unable to ever reach writeline("success 2!!") even if I render the rectangles and make sure I am hitting them in the order I created.

Thanks again guys.

Comment: Are both rectangles inside your panel?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand correctly what you are trying to do this won't work like this. Let me show this with an example:

```
Your rectangles don't touch each other (according to your coordinates):
      __________
     |          |
     |    1     |
     |          |
     |__________|
                   __________
                  |          |
                  |    2     |
                  |          |
                  |__________|
```

The event is triggered when you move the mouse inside Rect1. Let's go trough your code:

`if(Rect.Contains(Floater))` is definitly true.
Assuming that the left mouse button is pressed `Bdrag` is set to `true`.
`Console.WriteLine("success 1");` is triggered.
`if(Rect2.Contains(Floater) && Bdrag == true)` is definitly false, because `Floater` will always be inside Rect1 as it's position is only set when your mouse is inside Rect1.

When you move your mouse indise Rect2 now nothing happens. Why?

1. Your event is *probably* not triggered. I can't tell if it really is so as I can't see it in your code but it's likely because of the event's name.
2. Even if the event is triggered it will never pass the first if-statement, because obviously it is not in Rect1 any more.

**Solution:**

1. Make one method connected to **both** events with the following code:

   ```
   bool Bdrag;
   private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(200, 200 ,40 , 40);
       Rectangle Rect2 = new Rectangle(250, 250, 40, 40);
       if(Rect.Contains(new Point(e.X + Rect.Location.X, e.Y + Rect.Location.Y)))
       {
           if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
           {
               Bdrag = true;
           }
           else
           {
               Bdrag = false;
           }
       }
       if(Rect2.Contains(new Point(e.X + Rect2.Location.X, e.Y + Rect2.Location.Y)) && Bdrag == true)
       {
            //is executed when Rect2 has been hit after Rect1
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or make two seperated events:

   ```
   bool Bdrag;
   private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(200, 200 ,40 , 40);
           if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
           {
               Bdrag = true;
           }
           else
           {
               Bdrag = false;
           }
   }

   private void panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       Rectangle Rect2 = new Rectangle(250, 250, 40, 40);  
       if(Rect2.Contains(new Point(e.X + Rect2.Location.X, e.Y + Rect2.Location.Y)) && Bdrag == true)
       {
           //is executed when Rect2 has been hit after Rect1
       }          
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks you for taking your time with this answer, it doesn't work for me tho.

Comment: You're absolutly true! Now I had time testing it and I recognized that `Floater`is always in relative coordinates to the rectangle. I didn't know that but I'll change the answer :)

Comment: And thinking about your question shows me some other things: I made the assumption that the `rectangle`s are represented by panels on your form. Is this true? If it is so, I could show you a better way.

Comment: No they aren't panels if you can still help me that would be great!

Comment: Could you please describe the markup of your GUI? Because I don't know how the panel is integrated and which role it plays.